# What is matrix cross product as implemented by the R function `tcrossprod`?

Tags: python, r, numpy

I am new to cross product but from some resources I've understood what is cross product for vector and I understand how it's implemented by the numpy's function `np.cross()`. It's only defined for two or three dimensions and which is correct according to my understanding

But recently I also came across R's `tcrossprod` which implements cross product for arbitrarily large dimensions of matrices. Can you help me understand why is it different from `np.cross(A.T, A)` , what does it implement and what's the equivalent numpy function to do it.

Comment: Have you tried any sample data, to be able to detect similarities/differences?

Comment: I believe cross product is a mathematical concept, so no matter how any package has implemented it the outcome should be the same.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `R`, but playing with the examples in the documentation, it looks to me like `crossprod` and `tcrossprod` are variations on the matrix product, that is `np.dot`.  `np.cross` is an entirely different beast.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Generalizations talks about generalization of the cross product (as implemented by `np.cross`) to higher dimensions.  But that's getting into more advanced mathematics, with things like quaternions and exterior products.